# WPF databinding: database or objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, data-binding, object

I'm trying to create this:

Tag1 has the ordered list of objects: O1, O3, O2.
Tag2 has the ordered list of objects: O1, O4.

Every time I click a tag, I want to see the list of objects. So clicking Tag1 would show in a listbox:

- O1
- O3
- O2

But I would like to **keep the auto update so every time I edit or add/delete an object** it auto updates (I suppose I need to implement something like the interfaces `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`?).

I could use a database and have the tables Tag, Object and TagObject, this last one with the TagID and ObjectID. But I also would like to avoid databases, since it's a desktop application.

I could also use objects like `ObservableCollections`, but I have the problem of having duplicate objects. I can use references to the objects but it gets messy.

Anyone has any suggestion on how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create an object that contains a dataset (System.Data namespace). Inside the dataset it would have 3 tables that would be linked using defined foreign keys the same as if it was in a database. These can later be stored to XML if need be.

Your object would then have to expose a dataview which can be set as the datacontext and bound too.

Editing the dataset in code then updates the screen and editing the screen will update the dataset.

Comment: Thank you John. But the DataSet doesnt implement ICollectionChanged. Is the screen updated when I add a row to one table?

Comment: Odd though it seems and even though it does not implement ICollectionChanged it does work. I guess this is because it is not a collection but an XML based object.

Answer (score 1):

Move all the logic controlling the updated data out of the WPF page and into another class that *pushes* the new data into the WPF page, when it changes, rather than the WPF *pulling* the data out of the objects.

Here is some example code:

```
class WpfPage
{
   public List OrderedListForTag1 { set { /* whatever GUI binding code you need to deal with the new list for tag 1 */ }


   public List OrderedListForTag2 { set { /* whatever GUI binding code you need to deal with the new list for tag 2*/ }

}

class WpfPresenter
{
  WpfPage thePage;

  public void Tag1Selected()
  {
      //Calculate changes to 01, 02, 04 etcetce
      //If changed, update the page
      thePage.OrderedListForTag1 = //new list of objects
  }
}
```

This is one of the model-view-controller pattern(s) which is very common in GUI construction.  This [series of articles](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/05/23/build-your-own-cab-part-2-the-humble-dialog-box.aspx) covers the concepts.